# I'm getting invalid use of incomplete type class errors in C++, how do I correctly include header files?

Tags: c++, inheritance, include, clone, header-files

This question has been here before, but the solutions didn't work for my specific case (or I don't know how to transfer them to my code).
I have something like this (simplified to only the methods in question)

Calendar.hpp file:

```
#pragma once
#include "View.hpp"
class View;

class Calendar { 
View * v; 

public:
bool SetView(const View &newView) {
v = newView.clone(); 
return true; }
```

View.hpp file:

```
#pragma once
#include "Calendar.hpp"
class Calendar;

class View {
public:
View(){};
virtual View * clone() const = ;
```

YearView.hpp file:

```
#pragma once
#include "View.hpp"
class View;

YearView : public View {
public:
YearView(){};
View * clone() const override {
return new YearView(); }
```

When I compile I get "invalid use of incomplete type 'const class View'" error in line v = newView.clone();

What could be the reason for this please?
Alse, is there any way to include YearView.hpp in the Calendar.hpp file as well? I would like to use it to default set the 'v' in the constructor of Calendar to specific type YearView.

Comment: Look for Include guards and don't forward declare when you don't have to!

Comment: Sorry, forgot to type the #pragma once guards which are there. When should I forward declare? I though it would help recognize the classes in cyclic inclusions..

Answer (score 0):

You have a circular include between `calendar.hpp` and `view.hpp`, i presume you've tried to break this cycle by adding the forward declarations.

The problem is that you are using the forward declared classes in your headers. A forward declared class can only be used in declarations, you can't create new instances of the class or call any of its methods.

If you move the implementation of your methods into your cpp files then it should solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

`Calendar.hpp` includes `View.hpp` which includes `Calendar.hpp`... It's that cycle you need to break.

And you do it by *not* including `Calendar.hpp` in the `View.hpp` file. It should work because `View.hpp` doesn't actually use anything from `Calendar.hpp`.

So the `View.hpp` file should look something like

```
#pragma once

class View {
    ...
};
```

---

The forward declarations of `View` in the other header files is not needed, since you include the `View.hpp` file. And you need to include the `View.hpp` file because you use the `View` class for more than declarations.

Comment: Thank you, you lead me to the solution. View.hpp does actually use Calendar type in a different method, but a forward declaration is enough, I indeed, did not need to include it.

Comment: @chododom If you call a member function of `Calendar` then you need the header file. I suggest splitting the code into separate header and source files. Then you could possibly use forward declarations in the header file, and then include the full header files in the source files.

Comment: @chododom Also, this is one of the reasons it's so important with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).